# Where am I wrong about Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, outer-measure

I know there are many questions and answers about this lemma. But I can not grasp the idea.

[image]

Let my countable collection of measurable sets will look like (-1/n,1/n) where n goes from 1 to infinity.

Is it countable collection of measutable sets? Yes.

Then there are so many numbers which do not belong to any of our sets. But lemma says that almost all x belong to at most finitely many of our sets.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: While it is true that, for $E_n=\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$, almost all $x\in\Bbb R$ belong to finitely many of the $E_k$-s, Borel-Cantelli applies vacuously to that collection, because $\sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k)=\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your example:

$$
\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty = \{ ( -\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n} ) \}_{n=1}^\infty
$$

Then a given point $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|a|\geq \frac{1}{n}$, then $a$ lies in $0$ intervals. You are right here.

Now see the Lemma, 'at most finetely' means that for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$  one can find a finite number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$
number\,\, of\,\,intervals\,\,x\,\,belongs\,\,to \equiv m \leq n
$$

So, given the same $a$, we may use 1 and

$$
number\,\, of\,\,intervals\,\,a\,\,belongs\,\,to \equiv 0 < 1
$$

Comment: So: 1) 5 belongs to 0 interval. And it is consistent with the lemma.

Comment: 2) 0 belongs to infintely many intervals. And it is also consistent with the lemma because it says that "almost all x" not all.

Comment: Cheers! That's it

Comment: Is it correct ?

Comment: Fully correct!! Since a point has measure zero we may not look at it